# Scheme looping through an expression that contains lists

Tags: scheme

I am doing a question in Scheme which is to create a function which takes in an object and an expressions e.g `(foo 'x '(x 10 x x 4))` and has to return all of the objects that follow the given object, so the above function call would return `(10 x 4)`. However, the expression can also contain lists e.g `(foo 'y '(y (3 y 5 y y 8 9) (10 y 12 13 y 15 y) 17))` should return `((3 y 5 y y 8 9) 5 y 8 12 15)`. I am having trouble when they contain lists. Here is my code so far.

```
(define (foo target expression)
  (cond [(null? expression)]
        [(list? (first expression)) (foo target (first expression))]
        [(eqv? (first expression) target) (cons (first (rest expression)) (foo target (rest expression)))]
        [(not (eqv? (first expression) target)) (foo target (rest expression))]))
```

So when the expression contains a list, I am trying to recursively call the function on that list, however, I do not know how to get back to the original expression to continue searching.

So when I call `(foo 'y '(y (3 y 5 y y 8 9) (10 y 12 13 y 15 y) 17))` I am getting `((3 y 5 y y 8 9) 5 y 8 . #t)` so it successfully loops through the first list however it stops after that and does not reach the second list in the expression

Also, one other problem I am having is the boolean at the end of my result, I know this is because of the line `cond [(null? expression)]`, I added this because I was getting an error when it gets to the end of the expression, how can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that `(cons x (cons y ...` becomes a proper list only when you terminate it with the empty list `'()`. Hence `(cons x (cons y ... empty))` is proper, and equivalent to `(list x y ...)`, as opposed to what you have: `(cons x (cons y ... #t))`. You can fix this by making `'()` the result of your base case.

But you also need a second base case to test when the input list has less than 2 elements. This is because your function tries to access the second element later as `(first (rest expression))`. So in order to make sure that this is valid, you need to ensure that `expression` constains at least 2 elements. This can be done as `... (null? (rest expression)) ...` in your cond cases.

On the other hand, you function only iterates the first list element it encounters because of this line:

```
[(list? (first expression)) (foo target (first expression))]
```

In this case, you only handle `(first expression)`, but you need to handle both `(first expression)` and `(rest expression)`. Since you are reconstructing a list, you could use cons as:

```
(cons (foo target (first expression))
      (foo target (rest expression)))
```

but this recreates the depth of your original list. From your desired output examples, it seems that you want to flatten the result, so a better option would be to `append` them as:

```
(append (foo target (first expression))
        (foo target (rest expression)))
```

Consider the following rewrite:

```
(define (foo obj expr)
  (cond
    [(null? expr) #f]
    [(null? (rest expr)) '()]
    [(pair? (first expr))
     (append (foo obj (first expr))
             (foo obj (rest expr)))]
    [(equal? obj (first expr))
     (cons (second expr)
           (foo obj (rest expr)))]
    [else
     (foo obj (rest expr))]))
```

then you will have:

```
(foo 'x '(x 10 x x 4))
=> '(10 x 4)
(foo 'y '(y (3 y 5 y y 8 9) (10 y 12 13 y 15 y) 17))
=> '((3 y 5 y y 8 9) 5 y 8 12 15)
```

but you will also have:

```
(foo 'x '())
=> #f
(foo 'x '(x))
=> '()
```

Comment: Thank you for this, one more thing, one of the examples given in the question is `(foo 'z 'z) => ()`, how could I add this? It currently gives an error saying `rest: contract violation
  expected: (and/c list? (not/c empty?))
  given: z`

Comment: I have added `[(not (list? expr)) '()]` and it seems to work, is this correct?

Comment: You're correct. With that, you will output the empty list whenever the input expression is not a list. Just make sure to order it so that this is tested as your first base case.